# Keras false shape,

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

Hi does anybody know keras well? I cant understand what the problem is?
I got this problem :

```
ValueError: You are passing a target array of shape (1000, 1) while 
using as loss `categorical_crossentropy`. `categorical_crossentropy` 
expects targets to be binary matrices (1s and 0s) of shape (samples, 
classes). If your targets are integer classes, you can convert them to 
the expected format via...
from keras.utils import to_categorical
y_binary = to_categorical(y_int)


Alternatively, you can use the loss function ` 
sparse_categorical_crossentropy` instead, which does expect integer targets.
```

Hieer is the complete code:
https://ideone.com/v9yojt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change `categorical_crossentropy` with `binary_crossentropy`

in line 83 set:

```
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer="sgd", metrics=['accuracy'])
```